# How to transpose data from horizontal to vertical

Tags: excel, formatting, transpose

I have a text file I want to import into excel but the columns are horizontally arranged rather than vertically arranged.

My data looks like:

```
ID                 b1234
hi filter         .24321
lo filter          22
ID                 b5678
hi filter         .23355
lo filter          24
```

and I want it to look like:

```
ID        hi filter        lo filter 
b1234     .24321           22
b5678     .23355           24
```

I know transpose will re-arrange the column headings but rather than stacking the ID's in 1 column, hi filter in another, and lo filter in another, it puts each one in a long row adjacent to one another.  How can I get them "stacked?"

Comment: You will have to use VBA for this. You need to open the file as text and read three lines at a time into three variables which you concatenate into one line before reading the next three lines and doing the same on a new line.

Comment: You don't have to use VBA, however if you have a large amount of data it might be the preferred option to masses of formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Put your three titles across the top.  Then in the upper left corner of where the data will be put this formula:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,COLUMN(A:A)+(3*(ROW(1:1)-1)))
```

Then copy over and down.

[image]

Comment: Very nice formula!

Comment: This is the most beautiful thing I've seen all day.  Case Closed.

Comment: @scottCraner I guess e1v1s won't like my verbose answer options.  I think instead of answering I will get some rack time.

Comment: @scott really cool.  is there any tutorial or something i can read online to understand how to put together a formula like that.  even after evaluating the formula i still can't figure out how you plan it out to set it up that way with the use of the column and row and -1.  once again really great formula.